# How to pass a parameter in Angular Service?

Tags: angular, service, parameter-passing, angular-services

I am trying to pass a parameter to an api in Service but I am getting the value

https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=chicken

The above mentioned url is the right Url

In my service :

```js
loadSubCategoriesFood(name: string): Observable<{ meals: Meal[] }> {
  return this.http.get<{ meals: Meal[] }>(
    this.recipies.listofsubcategories + 'filter.php' + name
  );
}
```

TS :

```js
moveToCategories(foodname: string): void {
  this.home.loadSubCategoriesFood(foodname).subscribe((res) => {
    this.meals = res?.meals;
    console.log(this.meals);
  });
}
```

I am getting 404 in the console

https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.phpBeef 404

Comment: You are missing a small part when you create the URL in your service `?i=`. `this.recipies.listofsubcategories + 'filter.php?i=' + name`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `HttpParams` and define `i` as query parameter.

```
loadSubCategoriesFood(name: string): Observable<{ meals: Meal[] }> {
    const params = new HttpParams({
        fromObject: {
            i: name,
        },
    });
    return this.http.get<{ meals: Meal[] }>(
        this.recipies.listofsubcategories + 'filter.php',
        {
            params,
        }
    );
}
```